# Combining two numbers in prolog

Tags: prolog

Kindly, could you help me in the following:

I am writing a Prolog program that takes two <s>numbers</s> **digits** then combine them as one number, for example:

```
Num1: 5
Num2: 1
```

Then the new number is 51.

Assume `V1` is the first <s>number</s> **digit** and `V2` is the second <s>number</s> **digit**. I want to combine `V1` and `V2` then multiply the new number with `V3`, so my question is how I can do it?

```
calculateR(R, E, V1, V2, V3, V4):-
  R is V1 V2 * V3,
  E is R * V4.
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** In a comment, @false pointed out that this answer is SWI-Prolog specific.

You can achieve your desired goal by treating the numerals as atoms and concatenating them, and then converting the resultant atom into a number.

I'll use `atom_concat/3` to combine the two numerals. In this predicate, the third argument with be the combination of atoms in its first and second arguments. E.g.,

```
?- atom_concat(blingo, dingo, X).
X = blingodingo.
```

Note that, when you do this with two numerals, the result is an *atom* not a number. This is indicated by the single quotes enclosing the the result:

```
?- atom_concat(5, 1, X).
X = '51'.
```

But `51 \= '51'` and we cannot multiply an atom by number. We can use `atom_number/2` to convert this atom into a number:

```
?- atom_number('51', X).
X = 51.
```

That's all there is to it! Your predicate might look like this:

```
calculateR(No1, No2, Multiplier, Result) :-
    atom_concat(No1, No2, NewNoAtom),
    atom_number(NewNoAtom, NewNo),
    Result is NewNo * Multiplier.
```

Usage example:

```
?- calculateR(5, 1, 3, X).
X = 153.
```

Of course, you'll need more if you want to prompt the user for input.

I expect @Wouter Beek's answer is more efficient, since it doesn't rely on converting the numbers to and from atoms, but just uses the assumption that each numeral is a single digit to determine the resulting number based on their position. E.g., if 5 is in the 10s place and 1 is in the 1s place, then the combination of 5 and 1 will be `5 * 10 + 1 * 1`. The answer I suggest here will work with multiple digit numerals, e.g., in `calculateR(12, 345, 3, Result)`, `Result is 1234 * 3`. Depending on what you're after this may or may not be a desired result.

Comment: You are using SWI-specific behavior: `atom_concat(5,1,X)` produces a `type_error(atom,5)` or `type_error(atom,1)` in ISO -  GNU, SICStus, B, IF, Prolog IV ...

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. It worked for me and it was the simplest way.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another solution that is based on the idea of @aBathologist and that relies on ISO predicates only, and does not dependent on SWI's idiosyncratic modifications and extensions. Nor does it have most probably unwanted solutions like `calculateR('0x1',1,1,17).` nor `calculateR(1.0e+30,0,1,1.0e+300).`  Nor does it create unnecessary temporary atoms.

So the idea is to restrict the definition to decimal numbers:

```
digit_digit_number(D1, D2, N) :-
   number_chars(D1, [Ch1]),
   number_chars(D2, [Ch2]),
   number_chars(N, [Ch1,Ch2]).
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a straight-forward solution that should work in any Prolog close to ISO:

```
digits_radix_to_number(Ds, R, N) :-
   digits_radix_to_number(Ds, R, 0,N).

digits_radix_to_number([], _, N,N).
digits_radix_to_number([D|Ds], R, N0,N) :-
   N1 is D+N0*R,
   digits_radix_to_number(Ds, R, N1,N).

?- digits_radix_to_number([1,4,2],10,R).
   R = 142.
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a version which better clarifies the relational nature of Prolog - using `library(clpfd)` which is available in many Prolog systems (SICStus, SWI, B, GNU, YAP). It is essentially the same program as the one with `(is)/2` except that I added further *redundant constraints* that permit the system to ensure termination in more general cases, too:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

digits_radix_number(Ds, R, N) :-
   digits_radix_numberd(Ds, R, 0,N).

digits_radix_numberd([], _, N,N).
digits_radix_numberd([D|Ds], R, N0,N) :-
      D #>= 0, D #< R,
      R #> 0,
      N0 #=< N,
   N1 #= D+N0*R,
   digits_radix_numberd(Ds, R, N1,N).
```

Here are some uses:

```
?- digits_radix_number([1,4,2],10,N).
   N = 142.
?- digits_radix_number([1,4,2],R,142).
   R = 10.
?- digits_radix_number([1,4,2],R,N).
   R in 5..sup, 4+R#=_A, _A*R#=_B, _A in 9..sup, N#>=_A,
   N in 47..sup, 2+_B#=N, _B in 45..sup.
```

That last query asks for all possible radices that represent `[1,4,2]` as a number. As you can see, not anything can be represented that way. The radix has to be 5 or larger which is not surprising given the digit 4, and the number itself has to be at least 47.

Let's say we want to get a value between 1450..1500, what radix do we need to do that?

```
?- digits_radix_number([1,4,2],R,N), N in 1450..1500.
   R in 33..40, 4+R#=_A, _A*R#=_B, _A in 37..44,
   N in 1450..1500, 2+_B#=N, _B in 1448..1498.
```

Gnah, again gibberish. This answer contains many extra equations that have to hold. Prolog essentially says: Oh yes, there is a solution, provided all this fine print is true. Do the math yourself!

But let's face it: It is better if Prolog gives such hard-to-swallow answer than if it would say `Yes`.

Fortunately there are ways to remove such extra conditions. One of the simplest is called "labeling", where Prolog will "try out" value after value:

```
?- digits_radix_number([1,4,2],R,N), N in 1450..1500, labeling([],[N]).
   false.
```

That is  clear response now! There is no solution. All these extra conditions where essentially false, like all that fine print in your insurance policy...

Here's another question: Given the radix and the value, what are the required digits?

```
?- digits_radix_number(D,10,142).
   D = [1,4,2]
;  D = [0,1,4,2]
;  D = [0,0,1,4,2]
;  D = [0,0,0,1,4,2]
;  D = [0,0,0,0,1,4,2]
;  ... .
```

So that query can never terminate, because 00142 is the same number as 142. Just as 007 is agent number 7.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the radix of the numbers involved (and the radix is the same for all the numbers involved), then you can use the reverse index of the individual numbers in order to calculate their positional summation.

```
:- use_module(library(aggregate)).
:- use_module(library(lists)).

digits_to_number(Numbers1, Radix, PositionalSummation):-
  reverse(Numbers1, Numbers2),
  aggregate_all(
    sum(PartOfNumber),
    (
      nth0(Position, Numbers2, Number),
      PartOfNumber is Number * Radix ^ Position
    ),
    PositionalSummation
  ).
```

Examples of use:

```
?- digits_to_number([5,1], 10, N).
N = 51.
?- digits_to_number([5,1], 16, N).
N = 81.
```

(The code sample is mainly intended to bring the idea across. Notice that I use `aggregate_all/3` from SWI-Prolog here. The same could be achieved by using ISO predicates exclusively.)

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but really it is too complicated as I am new to prolog, is there is an easier way?

Comment: The `(**)/2` should rather be replaced by `(^)/2` to make it run in ISO conforming systems *and* SWI.

Comment: @false Thanks for pointing that out. We indeed need `^/2` to work on integers, whereas `**/2` works on floats.